# Xamarin UIPageViewController and memory management

Tags: ios, memory, xamarin, uipageviewcontroller

Dear stackoveflow users,

I have a problem with my project and could not find a solution.
I am trying to implement infinite scrolling on a `UIPageViewController`.
I created a `UIViewController` which has a `UIPageViewController` as child.
I implement my own GetNextViewController and GetPreviousViewController events to handle infinite scrolling and ordering of pages. I have 2 types of PageViews. 1 of them has a title and image and the other one has a avplayer.
Here is my `UIViewController` which has `UIPageViewController` as child.

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Drawing;
using SDWebImage;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using MonoTouch.FacebookConnect;

namespace MyApp
{
    [Register("MyPageViewController")]
    public class MyPageViewController : UIViewController
    {
        bool Loading;
        public int Page;
        public int PageType;
        public List<JObject> t = new List<JObject>();
        public int CurIndex;
        UIView toolbar = new UIView();
        JObject CommentData;
        bool isShown = true;
        UIPageViewController PageVC;
        MyActivity view;
        float barY;
        public MyPageViewController(IntPtr handle):base(handle){
        }
        public MyPageViewController (int type,int index,List<JObject> data,int page)
        {
            t = data;
            Page = page;
            PageType = type;
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            view = new MyActivity (this);
            View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
            UITapGestureRecognizer doubletap = new UITapGestureRecognizer();
            doubletap.NumberOfTapsRequired = 1;
            doubletap.AddTarget (this, new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector("DoubleTapSelector"));
            var firstPage = getPageByIndex (CurIndex);
            PageVC = new UIPageViewController (UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll,UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.Horizontal,UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation.Min,0.10f);
            PageVC.DidFinishAnimating += FinishedRotating;
            PageVC.GetNextViewController = _GetNextPageContentVC;
            PageVC.GetPreviousViewController = _GetPreviousPageContentVC;
            PageVC.SetViewControllers(new [] { firstPage }, UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, false, s => { });
            firstPage.Dispose ();
            PageVC.View.Frame = new RectangleF (0,0,View.Bounds.Width,View.Bounds.Height-50);
            View.AddSubview (PageVC.View);
            View.AddGestureRecognizer (doubletap);
            addToolbar ();
        }

        void addToolbar(){
            barY = View.Bounds.Height - 150;
            toolbar.Frame = new RectangleF (0,barY,View.Bounds.Width,50);
            toolbar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0,0,0,100);
            toolbar.AutosizesSubviews = true;
            var prev = new UIButton (UIButtonType.Custom);
            prev.Frame = new RectangleF (12, 0, 40, 40);
            prev.SetImage (UIImage.FromFile ("content-prev.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
            prev.Tag = -1;
            var extras = new UIButton (UIButtonType.Custom);
            extras.Frame = new RectangleF (63, 0, 40, 40);
            extras.SetImage (UIImage.FromFile ("c-more-icon.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
            var facebook = new UIButton (UIButtonType.Custom);
            facebook.Frame = new RectangleF (114, 0, 40, 40);
            facebook.SetImage (UIImage.FromFile ("c-share-icon.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
            var comment = new UIButton (UIButtonType.Custom);
            comment.Frame = new RectangleF (166, 0, 40, 40);
            comment.SetImage (UIImage.FromFile ("c-comment-icon.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
            var like = new UIButton (UIButtonType.Custom);
            like.Frame = new RectangleF (217, 0, 40, 40);
            like.SetImage (UIImage.FromFile ("c-like-icon.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
            var next = new UIButton (UIButtonType.Custom);
            next.Frame = new RectangleF (268, 0, 40, 40);
            next.SetImage (UIImage.FromFile ("content-next.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
            next.Tag = 1;
            prev.AutoresizingMask = next.AutoresizingMask = extras.AutoresizingMask = comment.AutoresizingMask = facebook.AutoresizingMask = like.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;
            prev.TouchUpInside += GotoPage;
            next.TouchUpInside += GotoPage;
            facebook.TouchUpInside += FaceTouch;
            extras.TouchUpInside += ExtrasTouch;
            comment.TouchUpInside += CommentsTouch;
            like.TouchUpInside += LikeTouch;

            toolbar.AddSubviews (new UIView[]{prev,extras,facebook,comment,like,next});
            View.AddSubview (toolbar);
        }

        [MonoTouch.Foundation.Export("DoubleTapSelector")]
        public void OnDoubleTap (UIGestureRecognizer sender) {
            if (isShown) {
                UIView.BeginAnimations ("hideToolbar");
                toolbar.Frame = new RectangleF (0,barY+50,View.Bounds.Width,0);
                UIView.CommitAnimations ();
                isShown = false;
            } else {
                UIView.BeginAnimations ("showToolbar");
                toolbar.Frame = new RectangleF (0,barY,View.Bounds.Width,50);
                UIView.CommitAnimations ();
                isShown = true;
            }
        }

        public void CommentsTouch(object sender, EventArgs e){
            JObject data = t [CurIndex-1];
            CommentData = data;
            PerformSegue ("Comment", (NSObject)sender);
        }

        public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender) {
            base.PrepareForSegue(segue, sender);
            Title = "Back";
            if (segue.Identifier == "Comment") {
                var comm = segue.DestinationViewController as MyComment;
                comm._data = CommentData;
            }
        }as child

        void GotoPage(object sender,EventArgs e){
            if (((UIButton)sender).Tag > 0) {
                if (CurIndex >= (t.Count - 3)) 
                {
                    GetDataByPage();
                }
                PageVC.SetViewControllers (new []{ getPageByIndex(CurIndex+1) }, UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward,true, s => { });
                CurIndex++;
            } else {
                if (CurIndex == 1)
                    return;
                PageVC.SetViewControllers (new []{ getPageByIndex(CurIndex-1) }, UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Reverse, true, s => { });
                CurIndex--;
            }
        }

        void FinishedRotating(object sender, UIPageViewFinishedAnimationEventArgs arg){
            if (arg.Completed) {
                if (PageVC.ViewControllers[0] is PageContentVC) {
                    CurIndex = ((PageContentVC)PageVC.ViewControllers[0]).PageIndex;
                } else {
                    CurIndex = ((MyVideoPage)PageVC.ViewControllers[0]).PageIndex;
                }
            }
        }


        UIViewController _GetPreviousPageContentVC(UIPageViewController pageController, UIViewController referenceViewController)
        {
            int pageIndex;
            if (CurIndex == 1)
                return null;
            else
                pageIndex = CurIndex-1;
            return getPageByIndex(pageIndex);   
        }

        UIViewController _GetNextPageContentVC(UIPageViewController pageController, UIViewController referenceViewController)
        {
            int pageIndex = CurIndex+1;
            if (CurIndex >= (t.Count - 5)) 
            {
                GetDataByPage();
            }
            if (CurIndex >= t.Count)
                return null;
            return getPageByIndex(pageIndex);   
        }

        public void ExtrasTouch (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            JObject data = t [CurIndex];
            view.Data = data;
            View.AddSubview (view.View);
            view.ViewWillAppear (false);
        }

        public UIViewController getPageByIndex(int index)
        {
            int type = int.Parse (t [index - 1] ["type"].ToString ());
            var data = t [index - 1];
            if (type == 4){ 
                return new MyVideoPage (index, data);
            }
            if(type == 3)
                return new PageContentVC (index,data);
            return new PageContentVC (index,data);
        }

        public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
            Title = "";
        }

        public async void GetDataByPage()
        {
            if (Loading)
                return;
            Loading = true;
            NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential ("xxx", "xxx");
            CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache ();
            myCache.Add (new Uri ("xxx"), "Basic", myCred);
            string url = "xxx" + Page + "/" + PageType;
            var request = WebRequest.Create (url);
            request.Credentials = myCache;
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";
            using (HttpWebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync () as HttpWebResponse) {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    Console.Out.WriteLine ("Error fetching data. Server returned status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (response.GetResponseStream ())) {
                    var content = reader.ReadToEnd ();
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (content)) {
                        //return ("Response contained empty body...");
                    } else {
                        string jpage = content;
                        var new_page = JArray.Parse (JObject.Parse (jpage).SelectToken ("conts").ToString ());
                        foreach (JObject j in new_page) {
                            t.Add (j);
                        }
                        Page --;
                        Loading = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Here are my other views.

PageView with Image :

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.Drawing;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using SDWebImage;
namespace MyApp
{
    public class PageContentVC : UIViewController
    {
        public int PageIndex {
            get;
            set;
        }
        readonly SizeF textWidth = new SizeF (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width-10 , float.MaxValue);
        UILabel title = new UILabel ();
        UIScrollView _ScrollView= new PageContentScrollView (new RectangleF (0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height)) {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear,
            MinimumZoomScale = 1f,
            MaximumZoomScale = 5.0f,
            ZoomScale = 1
        };
        JObject _data;
        UIImageView MyImage = new UIImageView ();
        UIActivityIndicatorView activity;
        string suff = "c";
        float width, height,sxposition,sheight,syposition;
        public PageContentVC (int pageIndex, JObject data)
        {
            PageIndex = pageIndex;
            _data = data;
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();
            Console.Out.WriteLine ("Here "+ PageIndex);
        }

        public override void ViewDidDisappear (bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidDisappear (animated);
            _ScrollView.SetZoomScale (1, false);
            MyImage.CancelCurrentImageLoad ();
            _data = null;
            _ScrollView.ViewForZoomingInScrollView -= delegate {
                return MyImage;
            };
        }

        public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear (animated);
            _ScrollView.ViewForZoomingInScrollView += delegate {
                return MyImage;
            };
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            activity = new UIActivityIndicatorView (UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge);
            float dwidth = float.Parse (_data ["width"].ToString ());
            float dheight = float.Parse (_data ["height"].ToString ());

            if (dwidth > 500) {
                dheight = dheight * 500 / dwidth;
                dwidth = 500;
            } else {
                suff = "o";
            }
            SizeF textSize = View.StringSize (System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(_data["title"].ToString()), title.Font, textWidth, UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);
            if (dwidth > View.Bounds.Width) {
                width = View.Bounds.Width;
                height = dheight * width / dwidth;
                if (height < View.Bounds.Height ) {
                    sheight = height;
                    syposition = (View.Bounds.Height - height) / 2;
                } else {
                    sheight = View.Bounds.Height;
                    syposition = 0;
                }
                sxposition = 0;
            } else {
                width = dwidth;
                height = dheight;
                sxposition = (View.Bounds.Width - width) / 2;
                if (height < View.Bounds.Height) {
                    sheight = height;
                    syposition = (View.Bounds.Height - height) / 2;
                } else {
                    sheight = View.Bounds.Height;
                    syposition = 0;
                }
            }
            _ScrollView.ContentSize = new SizeF(View.Bounds.Width,height+textSize.Height+59);
            title.Text = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(_data["title"].ToString());
            title.TextColor = UIColor.White;
            title.Lines = 0;
            title.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
            title.Frame = new RectangleF (new PointF((View.Bounds.Width-textSize.Width)/2,5), textSize);
            MyImage.Frame = new RectangleF (sxposition, textSize.Height + 10 , width, height);
            MyImage.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;
            MyImage.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
            int type = int.Parse(_data ["type"].ToString ());
            switch (type) 
            {
            case 1:
            case 6:
            case 5:
            case 2:
            case 9:                 
                activity.HidesWhenStopped = true;
                activity.Hidden = false;
                activity.StartAnimating ();
                activity.Center = new PointF (View.Bounds.Width / 2, View.Bounds.Height / 2);
                MyImage.SetImage (xxx ,null, SDWebImageOptions.RetryFailed, ProgressHandler, completedHandler);
                break;
            case 7:

                break;
            case 3:

                break;
            }
            _ScrollView.AddSubview (title);
            _ScrollView.AddSubview(MyImage);
            View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
            View.AddSubviews(new UIView[]{_ScrollView,activity});
        }

        void completedHandler (UIImage image, NSError error, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
        {
            if(image!=null)
            {
                MyImage.Image = image;
                activity.StopAnimating ();
                activity.RemoveFromSuperview ();
                activity.Dispose ();
            }
        }

        public void ProgressHandler (int recievedSize, int expectedSize)
        {

        }
    }
    }
```

And Here is my PageView with video.

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.AVFoundation;
using SDWebImage;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class MyVideoPage : UIViewController
    {
        public JObject Data;
        NSObject _playbackObserver;
        AVPlayer _player;
        AVPlayerItem _playerItem;
        AVPlayerLayer _playerLayer;
        AVAsset _asset;
        int _PageIndex;
        public int PageIndex {
            get {
                return _PageIndex;
            }
        }
        bool init = false;
        readonly UIActivityIndicatorView activity = new UIActivityIndicatorView (UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge);
        public MyVideoPage (int index,JObject data)
        {
            _PageIndex = index;
            Data = data;
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
            float dheight = float.Parse (Data ["height"].ToString());
            float dwidth = float.Parse (Data ["width"].ToString());
            float width, height,syposition,sxposition,sheight;
            if (dwidth > View.Bounds.Width) {
                width = View.Bounds.Width;
                height = dheight * width / dwidth;
                if (height < View.Bounds.Height) {
                    syposition = (View.Bounds.Height - height) / 2;
                    sheight = height;
                } else {
                    syposition = 0;
                    sheight = View.Bounds.Height;
                }
                sxposition = 0;
            } else {
                width = dwidth;
                height = dheight;
                sxposition = (View.Bounds.Width - width) / 2;
                if (height < View.Bounds.Height) {
                    syposition = (View.Bounds.Height - height) / 2;
                    sheight = height;
                } else {
                    syposition = 0;
                    sheight = View.Bounds.Height;
                }
            }
            activity.HidesWhenStopped = true;
            activity.Hidden = false;
            activity.StartAnimating ();
            activity.Center = new PointF (View.Bounds.Width / 2, View.Bounds.Height / 2);
            _asset = AVAsset.FromUrl (new NSUrl (xxx));
            _playerItem = new AVPlayerItem (_asset);
            _player = new AVPlayer (_playerItem);
            _playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer.FromPlayer (_player);
            if (height > View.Bounds.Height) {
                _playerLayer.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 0, width, height);
                var _ScrollView = new UIScrollView ();
                _ScrollView.Frame = new RectangleF (sxposition, syposition, width, sheight);
                _ScrollView.ContentSize = new SizeF (width, height);
                _ScrollView.Layer.AddSublayer (_playerLayer);
                View.AddSubview (_ScrollView);
            } else {
                _playerLayer.Frame = new RectangleF (sxposition, syposition, width, height);
                View.Layer.AddSublayer (_playerLayer);
            }           
            View.AddSubview (activity);
        }

        public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear (animated);
            _player.AddObserver (this, new NSString ("status"), 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            _playbackObserver = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver ("AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification", notify => {
                _player.Seek (MonoTouch.CoreMedia.CMTime.Zero);
                _player.Play ();
                notify.Dispose ();
            },_playerItem);
            init = true;
        }

        public override void ViewDidDisappear (bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidDisappear (animated);
            if (init) {
                _player.RemoveObserver (this, new NSString ("status"));
                _player.Seek (MonoTouch.CoreMedia.CMTime.Zero);
                NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver (_playbackObserver, "AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification", _playerItem);
                init = false;
            }
            Data = null;
            Dispose ();
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();
            Console.Out.WriteLine ("Here "+ PageIndex);
        }

        public override void ObserveValue (NSString keyPath, NSObject ofObject, NSDictionary change, IntPtr context)
        {
            if (ofObject == _player && keyPath.ToString () == "status") {
                if (_player.Status == AVPlayerStatus.ReadyToPlay) {
                    _player.Play ();
                    activity.StopAnimating ();
                    activity.RemoveFromSuperview ();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I override `DidReceiveMemoryWarning` to print out views PageIndex to see which of them are alive. When I started to scroll UIPageViewController memory starts to grow. And after some scroll I am getting memory warning and here is an example of memory warning output.

```
2014-04-28 11:29:37.144 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 123
2014-04-28 11:29:37.146 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 89
2014-04-28 11:29:37.148 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 116
2014-04-28 11:29:37.149 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 8
2014-04-28 11:29:37.150 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 115
2014-04-28 11:29:37.150 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 90
2014-04-28 11:29:37.152 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 52
2014-04-28 11:29:37.153 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 120
2014-04-28 11:29:37.153 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 25
2014-04-28 11:29:37.154 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 64
2014-04-28 11:29:37.155 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 83
2014-04-28 11:29:37.156 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 74
2014-04-28 11:29:37.157 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 56
2014-04-28 11:29:37.158 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 27
2014-04-28 11:29:37.159 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 79
2014-04-28 11:29:37.160 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 117
2014-04-28 11:29:37.161 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 24
2014-04-28 11:29:37.162 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 41
2014-04-28 11:29:37.163 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 45
2014-04-28 11:29:37.164 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 84
2014-04-28 11:29:37.165 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 112
2014-04-28 11:29:37.166 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 96
2014-04-28 11:29:37.168 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 125
2014-04-28 11:29:37.169 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 57
2014-04-28 11:29:37.170 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 10
2014-04-28 11:29:37.171 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 13
2014-04-28 11:29:37.172 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 119
2014-04-28 11:29:37.174 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 12
2014-04-28 11:29:37.175 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 19
2014-04-28 11:29:37.176 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 40
2014-04-28 11:29:37.177 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 21
2014-04-28 11:29:37.179 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 126
2014-04-28 11:29:37.181 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 93
2014-04-28 11:29:37.182 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 88
2014-04-28 11:29:37.183 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 109
2014-04-28 11:29:37.185 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 98
2014-04-28 11:29:37.187 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 68
2014-04-28 11:29:37.190 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 103
2014-04-28 11:29:37.191 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 120
2014-04-28 11:29:37.192 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 126
2014-04-28 11:29:37.193 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 122
2014-04-28 11:29:37.194 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 2
2014-04-28 11:29:37.196 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 47
2014-04-28 11:29:37.197 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 87
2014-04-28 11:29:37.198 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 119
2014-04-28 11:29:37.199 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 42
2014-04-28 11:29:37.200 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 51
2014-04-28 11:29:37.202 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 32
2014-04-28 11:29:37.203 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 110
2014-04-28 11:29:37.204 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 50
2014-04-28 11:29:37.205 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 35
2014-04-28 11:29:37.206 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 46
2014-04-28 11:29:37.208 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 4
2014-04-28 11:29:37.209 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 37
2014-04-28 11:29:37.210 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 92
2014-04-28 11:29:37.211 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 60
2014-04-28 11:29:37.212 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 121
2014-04-28 11:29:37.213 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 65
2014-04-28 11:29:37.214 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 9
2014-04-28 11:29:37.215 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 16
2014-04-28 11:29:37.216 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 6
2014-04-28 11:29:37.217 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 75
2014-04-28 11:29:37.218 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 85
2014-04-28 11:29:37.219 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 20
2014-04-28 11:29:37.220 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 81
2014-04-28 11:29:37.221 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 94
2014-04-28 11:29:37.222 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 3
2014-04-28 11:29:37.224 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 43
2014-04-28 11:29:37.225 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 7
2014-04-28 11:29:37.226 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 78
2014-04-28 11:29:37.227 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 23
2014-04-28 11:29:37.229 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 67
2014-04-28 11:29:37.230 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 111
2014-04-28 11:29:37.231 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 49
2014-04-28 11:29:37.232 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 105
2014-04-28 11:29:37.233 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 101
2014-04-28 11:29:37.234 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 54
2014-04-28 11:29:37.235 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 33
2014-04-28 11:29:37.236 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 39
2014-04-28 11:29:37.237 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 106
2014-04-28 11:29:37.239 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 11
2014-04-28 11:29:37.240 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 99
2014-04-28 11:29:37.241 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 107
2014-04-28 11:29:37.242 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 17
2014-04-28 11:29:37.243 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 31
2014-04-28 11:29:37.244 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 129
2014-04-28 11:29:37.292 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 28
2014-04-28 11:29:37.293 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 71
2014-04-28 11:29:37.294 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 50
2014-04-28 11:29:37.296 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 61
2014-04-28 11:29:37.298 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 97
2014-04-28 11:29:37.300 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 15
2014-04-28 11:29:37.301 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 29
2014-04-28 11:29:37.302 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 36
2014-04-28 11:29:37.304 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 70
2014-04-28 11:29:37.305 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 117
2014-04-28 11:29:37.306 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 59
2014-04-28 11:29:37.307 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 77
2014-04-28 11:29:37.308 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 102
2014-04-28 11:29:37.310 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 114
2014-04-28 11:29:37.311 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 63
2014-04-28 11:29:37.312 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 72
2014-04-28 11:29:37.313 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 1
2014-04-28 11:29:37.315 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 128
2014-04-28 11:29:37.316 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 129
2014-04-28 11:29:37.317 MyApp[1167:60b] Here 130
```

Old PageViews are still alive and I could not find the reason.
Could you please help me to find my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure anything more out?

Comment: Although I share some of your sentiment I was able to come up with an answer. See my answer below.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to subclass UIPageViewController and override FinishedAnimating and SetViewControllers.

In SetViewControllers it now looks like:

```
//Each time SetViewControllers is called we want to make sure we dispose of any previous controllers
var childControllers = ChildViewControllers;
foreach (var child in childControllers)
    child.Dispose ();

base.SetViewControllers (viewControllers, direction, animated, completionHandler);
```

In FinishedAnimating

```
if (ViewControllers.Length == 0 || ViewControllers [0] == null || e.Completed == false)
                return;

//Any other stuff you need to update based on new current controller, etc.

//Cleanup non adjacent controllers
var childControllers = ChildViewControllers;
foreach (BaseMediaItemController childController in childControllers)
        if (childController.Index < (CurrentIndex - 1) || childController.Index > (CurrentIndex + 1))
                childController.Dispose ();
```

This allows me to properly dispose of my view controllers when using UIPageViewController in an infinite fashion. In my case I sometimes call SetViewControllers when my data changes so that is why I also need to dispose of any previous child controllers there.